# How to make a Variable for each element in a list?

Tags: c#, list, variables

I'm trying to create a program that can check which user has the most jobs at once on our cluster. I have a list of all the users and a seperate list for all unique users. I need to create a variable for each unique users to store the amount of times that user was mentioned in the other list. This is in C# and any heal is REALLY appreciated. Thank you!

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TextScanner
{
    class Niam
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            NameCounters TheCounters = new NameCounters();
            List<string> TheNames = TheCounters.UniqueUserNames;
            char[] IgnoredChars = { ' ' };
            Console.WriteLine ("Enter the path to the text document you'd like to use.");
            string Path = Console.ReadLine ();
            string line;
            StreamReader TheFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(Path);
            List<string> NameCollection = new List<string>();
            while ((line = TheFile.ReadLine ()) != null)
            {
                string[] words = line.Split(IgnoredChars, System.StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
                string Users = words [3];
                NameCollection.Add(Users);
            }
            TheCounters.NameCounter (NameCollection);
            NameCollection.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
            Console.WriteLine ("List of Unique Users: ");
            TheNames.ForEach (Console.WriteLine);
            for (int l = 0; l < TheNames.Count; l++) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine (l);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Other class:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace TextScanner
{
    public class NameCounters
    {
        public List<string> UniqueUserNames = new List<string> ();

        public void NameCounter (List<string> Names)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Names.Count; i++)
            {
                //string s = Names [i];
                if (!UniqueUserNames.Contains(Names[i])) 
                {
                    UniqueUserNames.Add (Names [i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I need to create a variable for each unique users to store the amount of times that user was mentioned in the other list." I see no reason for that. It sounds like you just need a `Dictionary<string, int>`, mapping a user name to the number of times you've seen that name. Additionally, I'd suggest you look into .NET naming conventions, and keeping fields private. (Also, most C# doesn't have quite that many spaces, e.g. for indexer access, method calls etc.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, I will try it out :)